# parentsUntil() stops after going up only one level

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Here's a picture of the DOM:
http://screencast.com/t/o9CZQMO0o

```
$(".dialogue .delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bubble = $(this).parentsUntil(".questions");
    alert(bubble.html()); return;
});
```

When clicking delete i want to alert the content of the div with classes 'dialogue' and 'customer', but instead i only get the content of the div with class 'manage'.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: post html code here, when you solve problem question will not make sense any more

Comment: closest() worked! How come parentsUntil() will not? I've used it a thousand times before..

Comment: it's quite a lot of html code

Answer (score 2):

In this case parentsUntil() will not work since it gives an array of elements. ie `['.manage', '.showView', '.bubble', '.dialog']` that is all elements between current element and the one specified by the selector `.questions`

Then when you call `.html()` on this collection of elements, it gives the html contents first element. In this case it is the `.manage` element.

If you use `closest()` here, you will get only one element, which satisfies the passes selector